# How to keep SimpleMessageListenerContainer active until all threads which are using this container get's shutdown

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

Getting logs as below once the server is stopped

> 2020-04-01 01:34:44.353  INFO ABC --- [       Thread-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Shutdown ignored - container is not active already

code block of  SimpleMessageListenerContainer

```
@Bean
    public RabbitListenerContainerFactory<SimpleMessageListenerContainer> rabbitListenerContainerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        factory.setAcknowledgeMode(AcknowledgeMode.NONE);
        factory.setAfterReceivePostProcessors(m -> {
            m.getMessageProperties().setContentType("text/plain");
            return m;
        });
        return factory;
    }
```

Consumer class is as below

```
@Component
public class ConsumerOne {

    @RabbitListener(queues = "queue_one"},containerFactory = "rabbitListenerContainerFactory")
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        try {
            LOGGER.info(message);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.error("EXCEPTION ",message, e);
        }
    }
}
```

I have multiple consumer class for multiple queues. Thanks in advance

Comment: What problem is this causing? It just looks like a second thread is asking the container to stop when it has already been stopped. What is `Thread-2`? You can just ignore this log (or set the log level to WARN).

Comment: once i restarted the server it's taking around 2 to 3 minutes of time to get started this is the problem what it causing.  And this behaviour is because of around 200 consumers class which are linked to SimpleMessageListenerContainer. Thread-2 is the one which is linked to some consumer class.

Answer (score 0):

I have just determined that this is a bogus message; the container itself is emitting that erroneous log.

You can safely ignore it.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/1317